# Texts in a file not printing properly

Tags: ruby, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

Working through this problem and I have typed out the code EXACTLY like the problem states - even tried to copy and paste to see if it was something I was doing wrong but its not.

The code that I have is at the bottom of this post. I am sending the argument 'test.txt' which contains:

```
This is stuff I typed into a file. 
It is really cool stuff. 
Lots and lots of fun to have in here
```

however, when i run the code, during the print_all(current_file) it ONLY prints 'lots and lots of fun to have here.' - which is the last line of the file.

And where it is supposed to print out each individual line, it prints:

```
1 ["This is stuff I typed into a file. \rIt is really cool stuff. \rLots and lots of fun to have in here.\r\r"]
2 []
3 []'
```

essentially capturing all lines as 1 line, and printing nothing where its supposed to print line 2 and 3.

Any ideas?

```
input_file = ARGV[0]

def print_all(f)
  puts f.read()
end

def rewind(f)
  f.seek(0, IO::SEEK_SET)
end

def print_a_line(line_count, f)
  puts "#{line_count} #{f.readlines()}"
end

current_file = File.open(input_file)

puts "First let's print the whole file:"
puts # a blank line

print_all(current_file)

puts "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

puts "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line += 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** 
It looks like the test file you are using only contains the character `\r` to indicate a newline, instead of the windows `\r\n` or the linux `\n`. Your text editor may interpret `\r` as a newline, but ruby doesn't.

Original answer:

As for you first problem with `print_all`, I couldn't reproduce it. How do you run the script?

In the second problem, you are using the method `file.readlines()` (note the final **s**) instead of `file.readline()`.

[`file.readlines()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-readlines) reads the *entire* file and returns its content in an array, with each line as an element of the array.
This is why you get your whole file in the first call. Subsequent calls return the empty array because you are the end of the file (you'd need to "rewind" as you did previously to continue reading from the file).

[`file.readline()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-readline) reads one line of the file and returns its content as a string, which is probably what you want.

I linked to the ruby documentation for further reads (no pun intended) about the question. Note that the relevant methods are detailed in the documentation for the `IO` class, since `File` inherits from this class and the readlines/readline methods are inherited from `IO`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding your first question, i run the script in terminal: ruby Lesson20.rb test.txt

Comment: Regarding your second statement - i actually used the readlineS it was the only way i could get the code to run. Using readline i get the following error

Comment: lesson20.rb:12:in `readline': end of file reached (EOFError)
 from lesson20.rb:12:in `print_a_line'
 from lesson20.rb:32:in `<main>'

Comment: Thanks for you input. `EOFError`is typically raised when one call readline on a file and there is no more line to read. That means that what appears to be three lines in your file is actually treated as one.

Comment: This has been resolved now - dureuill stated that he couldnt reproduce my first problem I figured it may be an issue with the file I am actually using as an argument.

So i created a new file and tested the code by passing it that - and it worked.

There must be something wrong with the file I was trying to use - I had used it during previous exersizes when learning file access so perhaps something is messed up with a pointer.